# MSMQ not working on Windows 8 machine

Tags: c#, msmq

I am trying to use MSMQs as below

```
string _QueueName = "\\MyServer\MyQueue";
if ( MessageQueue.Exists(_QueueName) ) // Error here
{
    _Queue = new MessageQueue(@"FormatName:DIRECT=OS:" + _QueueName);
    _Queue.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(MyItem) });

}
```

My application compiles and runs successfully on windows 7 64 bit machine. If I take the same dlls on windows 8.1 and run without compiling on 8.1, I get this error

> An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

Please note that both are 64 bit machines. I have installed MSMQ Windows Features on both machines. Any ideas what could be the problem?

The event viewer displays

ERROR in MyApplication.MyFunction An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

```
Call Stack: 
at 
System.Messaging.Interop.SafeNativeMethods.IntMQPathNameToFormatName(String pathName, StringBuilder formatName, Int32& count)
at System.Messaging.Interop.SafeNativeMethods.MQPathNameToFormatName(String pathName, StringBuilder formatName, Int32& count)
at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.ResolveFormatNameFromQueuePath(String queuePath, Boolean throwException)
at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.Exists(String path)
```

Comment: If you open Event Viewer `Windows + R -> eventvwr.exe` do you see any details about this exception?

Comment: I have added the event viewer error in the question

Comment: Try to provide full path in `MessageQueue.Exists` such as `.\\MyQueue`

Comment: I tried that. Please note my queue is on a different machine. I have updated code in the question

Comment: The application is trying to load a 64-bit DLL while running as 32-bit, or vice versa. Try marking your application explicitly as either 32-bit or 64-bit (this can be done without recompiling by using the `corflags` utility). You can also consider checking your `PATH` -- the method in question imports from `mqrt.dll`, without explicitly specifying a location. There are various fascinating ways in which Windows locates appropriate DLLs, which this comment is too small to contain, and there may well be changes between W7 and W8.1 (or just your machines specifically).

Comment: There is c:\windows\system32\mqrt.dll and c:\windows\syswow64\mqrt.dll.  Respectively the 64-bit and the 32-bit implementation DLL for message queues, not a typo.  This machine has these DLLs messed-up.  MSMQ has to be installed separately, one reason why this could be corrupted.  Nothing a thorough disk reformat could not fix.

Comment: My application is 32 bit. I have tried ANY CPU and x86 but in both cases MSMq does not work on windows 8.1 but on Windows 7 (64 bit) all works fine